# SuiteScript 2.0 - set scheduled percentage complete value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to convert a script that contains setPercentComplete from nlapiGetContext() function.  That allows me to set the percentage complete value.

I am not seeing anything in regards to setting this for SuiteScript 2.0 has anyone discovered how to do that yet?

Comment: I have actually been looking at this as well.  I have a case open with NetSuite to find out how to perform this in 2.0.  I'll post their answer, when I receive it.

Answer (score 1):

`runtime` module's script object has got `percentComplete` as read-only property.

```
runtime.getCurrentScript().percentComplete
```

I could not find a way to set it.

Comment: According to Netsuite's docs, the field is get/set

https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4296662993.html

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code that will work.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/runtime','N/record'],function(runtime,record){
  return {
    execute:function(context){
      var script=runtime.getCurrentScript();
      for(x=0;x<500;x++){
        var rec=record.create({type:'salesorder'});
        script.percentComplete=(x*100)/500;                               
      }
    }
  };
});
```